# Change of narration

Tags: reported-speech

What is the indirect speech of the following sentence?

"The vendor is creating chaos, with sellers asking, How many kilos of fish were given?"

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe the example is wrong. The indirect speech should be:

... with sellers asking how many kilos of fish were given.

Direct would be:

The sellers asked, "How many kilos of fish were given?".

With direct speech you quote the speaker directly, whereas with indirect speech you report what they said.

Comment: the inverted comma was for whole sentence not for the wh word